# integration - brute force vs substitution

Tags: integration

The correct answer (using brute force) for $\int_{0}^{1} x(1-x)^3dx$ is $1/20$. But when I use substitution, i.e., $u = 1 -x $

$-\int_{0}^{1} (1-u)(u)^3du$

$-\int_{0}^{1} u^3-u^4du$

The answer is $-1/20$ since $dx = -du$. Am I doing the substitution wrongly? Am I supposed to get the same answer as the brute force approach using substitution?

Question solved: careless mistake on my part, forgot to adapt the integral bounds according to the new variable $u = 1-x$

Comment: When you substitute, you must adapt the integral limits. You get $-\int_1^0 u^3 - u^4\,du$. Use the leading $-$ to switch the integral limits and get $\int_0^1 u^3-u^4\,du$.

Comment: Why and how do I reverse the bounds? Is there a rule for that?

Comment: put  the value of bounds on $x$ in your substitution formula to get the corresponding value of bounds on $u$

Comment: Since $u = 1-x$, originally the lower bound $x=0$ should become $u=1$, the upper bound $x=1$ should become $u=0$.

Comment: $0 = x = 1-u \leadsto u = 1-x = 1-0$, and $1 = x = 1-u \leadsto u = 1-x = 1-1$. It's maybe a bit unfortunate that here the substitution leads to flipping the limits.

Comment: Oh my, that's an oversight on my part... I understand where I made a mistake now. Thank you!